# How to stop contextmenu in visualstudio 2008 from dissapearing

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Whenever I rightclick something in visualstudio, I get a context menu for about half a second. Then it goes away, before I got a chance to click anything.  Sometimes if I'm really fast I manage to click something anyway, then it works.

So annoying.

Sometimes the problem goes away for a few hours, then it comes back (in the sams visual studio instance).  I tried uninstalling all plugins, reinstalling visual studio, all to no avail).

This doesn't happen in any other program.

I am hoping somebody else has seen this problem and found a way to fix it.

WinXP, Visual Studio 2008.

PS I hope this question doesn't fall outside the scope of stackoverflow.

Comment: unfortunately none of these suggestions work. I guess reinstalling windows is the only option left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody running into this in the future:

Reinstalling made this problem go away.   Reinstalling VisualSVN made this problem come back.
Reinstalling fixed it again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a different mouse?  Replaced the batteries in a wireless one etc.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using the menu key on your keyboard and see if that has any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed SP1? I seem to remember seeing something like this before and thought that it was this issue (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB947751) but having re-read your question maybe not?